# "Myself" as a single subject

Tags: grammaticality, subjects, reflexives

How do we use *myself* as the only subject of a sentence?

For example I once heard some people saying *Myself am to be blamed.* Is this grammatically correct? How is it different from *I am to be blamed*?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not grammatically correct, which is how it's different from `I am to be blamed.`, which is. You might use it if you heard that the news media were going to publish a story blaming you. But it you wanted to state something was your fault, you wouldn't say that, you'd say **blame me** or **it's my fault**.

**I myself am to be blamed** is grammatically correct too, and means the same as **I am to be blamed** (by the media etc.) but adds emphasis that **you** are to be blamed rather than someone else perhaps more deserving of blame.

**Myself, I prefer driving to cycling** is also grammatically correct, and again, the addition of **myself** adds a certain emphasis: rather than a detatched fact about your preference, it suggests comparison, in response to another person's preference just mentioned.

Comment: The latter example might be considered a short form of "speaking for myself", which (as you say) emphasizes that this is a statement of opinion.

Comment: It's not customary, certainly, but I hesitate to say that it is not grammatical.

Comment: I'll say it's not grammatical. Google hits for "Myself am to be blamed" -"I myself am to be blamed" total one. OP.